# d-separation from A given hard evidence on B and E

Tags: bayesian, causality, bayesian-network

[image]

The problem in question is 4.

For the life of me I cannot figure out the solution, can someone explain how its done? From my attempts it appears that nothing is d-separated from A if evidence in B and E, but this is wrong.

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph (see 
[here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). When you retype the question,
add the `[self-study]` tag & read 
[its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. 
We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When not conditioning, colliding paths $\rightarrow \leftarrow$ are closed and other paths are open. When conditioning, the opposite happens: collider paths are opened (when conditioning on the collider or descendant of the collider) and the other paths are closed.

Thus, conditioning on $B$ opens the path $A \rightarrow B \leftarrow C$ and $A$ *will not* be separated from the variables downstream that directed path to $C, D$ and $H$.

But conditioning on $E$ closes the path $A \rightarrow E \rightarrow F$. Thus, $A$ is d-separated from $F$ and $G$, since the other paths to reach them are via colliders $D$ or $H$ which are not conditioned on.

Comment: After re-reading the rules and your post it now makes sense, thank you!